# Regex em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como seria uma regex para pegar apenas numeros e / num string.

Exemplo: Data de inicio: 29/08/2016

Resultado: 29/08/2016

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com [essa pergunta no Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy), a maneira simples sugerida é:

```
/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/
```

Porém essa expressão como ([relatado em um comentário](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy#comment19117980_5465426)) da resposta **não é correta para 29 de fevereiro**,

um outro usuários sugeriu a seguinte expressão:

```
var reg = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g;
```

Que apesar de ser muito mais complexa é a que venho usado, nunca encontrei erros nela.

Na mesma pergunta você vai encontrar maneiras de válidar a data por meio de functions ao invés de usar regex, se for mais interessante para você, por que não?

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer assim:

```js
var data1 = "Data de inicio: 29/08/2016";
var data2 = data1.replace(/[^0-9/]/g, '');
document.write(data2);
```